# Изменение значения через заданный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующее:

Нужно чтобы при каждом шаге `i`, изменялось `$('#test').val(i)` от 0 до 100. Т.е. сейчас сразу присваивается 100, но как сделать чтобы оно было 0, интервал, 10, интервал, 20 и тд. ? Пробовал и циклы, и перебор массива, но как обновлять val при каждом шаге я, увы, не понимаю.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10) {
    $('#test').val(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">btn</button>
<input id="test" type="text" value="0">
```

Получилось вот так, если можно как-то улучшить/упростить - дайте знать

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var i = 0;
  var fadeInTimer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').val(i);
    i += 10;
    if (i == 110) {
      clearInterval(fadeInTimer);
    };
  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click</button>
<input id="test" type="text" value="0">
```

Comment: Сначала надо задать шаг, а потом уже обновлять val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет setInterval() , вот ссылка как ее пользоваться (если надо)
https://learn.javascript.ru/task/setinterval-result